# How can I get the letters after the dot using PHP?

Tags: php

How can I get the letters after the dot using PHP?

example:

```
$index = "index.php"; //php
$path = "images/user.png"; //png
$location = "download/client.rar"; //rar
$extend = "js/jQuery.min.js"; //js
```

How can I get the letters from the right of the last dot (.) ??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: There are a lot of examples. Why you didn't ask any search engine?

Answer (score 4):

Simples,

```
end(explode(".",$string));
```

So for example,

```
$extend = "js/jQuery.min.js"; //js
end(explode(".",$extend)); // will return .js
```

If you're getting the strict standards error, you're going to need to split the functions, or update to the latest PHP where this is supported.

```
$extend = "js/jQuery.min.js"; //js
$explode = explode(".",$extend);
$end = end($explode);
```

Comment: OK thank you, I though the error "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference" won't be gone. Thanks.

Comment: There are 3 things you can do, split the functions like I've shown, update your PHP to the latest or disable error checking. I highly recommend you don't do the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[PATHINFO](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)** in php

like this :

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('index.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n"; // here the extension
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ext = (strpos($str, '.') !== false) ? substr($str, strrpos($str, '.')+1) : $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string = "js/jQuery.min.js";
$arr = explode('.',$string);
$last = array_slice($arr, -1, 1, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)**.

```
$file = 'test/file/name.ext';

// ext
$extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want extension of file specifically, use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function :

```
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

else, in general, you can use  :

```
$endpart = end(explode('.', $path));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Following:**

```
<?php

// your file
$file = 'image.jpg';

$info = pathinfo($file);

$file_name =  $info['extension'];

echo $file_name; // outputs 'jpg'

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$location = "download/client.rar";

echo pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);